# Как открыть сайт на ПК (локально), написанный c помощью OPENCART?

Tags: opencart, веб-сервер

Всем здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема.

Заказал сайт на диплом, написали, всё было вроде бы хорошо. Но после 10 дней он перестал работать (сервер не найден), разработчик не отвечает, что делать, не знаю.
Есть только файлы, скопированные с сервера.
В какой программе можно открыть? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: > заказал сайт на диплом

вот отсюда поподробнее[.](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/901/414/8a6.gif)

Comment: для дипломной работы нужен был сайт, который потом нужно описать

Comment: при чём он должен быть с личным кабинетом, калькулятором, и возможностью заказа оборудования.

Comment: @Антон Горностаев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно установить локальный веб. сервер. OpenCart у нас на php, значит подойдет

1. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/download.html)
2. [Denver](http://www.denwer.ru/)
3. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/)

Выбирайте любой. Дальше нужно закинуть файлы вашего движка в нужную директорию и запустить веб-сервер. Тонкости будут зависить от выбранного Вами инструмента.